# Sum different Excel files conditional to column value

Tags: r, excel, list

I have download data from a website and keep each year in different sheets (as a list).

Each sheet, which are named year+semester, looks like this:

```
structure(list(age = c("0 anys", "1 any", "2 anys", "3 anys", 
"4 anys", "5 anys", "6 anys", "7 anys", "8 anys", "9 anys", "10 anys", 
"11 anys", "12 anys", "13 anys", "14 anys", "15 anys", "16 anys", 
"17 anys", "18 anys", "19 anys", "20 anys", "21 anys", "22 anys", 
"23 anys", "24 anys", "25 anys", "26 anys", "27 anys", "28 anys", 
"29 anys"), total = c("57.332", "59.891", "59.721", "64.547", 
"66.679", "71.402", "74.597", "77.058", "78.023", "77.638", "82.241", 
"84.507", "86.972", "87.636", "91.099", "87.265", "87.807", "87.160", 
"87.492", "86.312", "84.483", "84.573", "86.935", "85.666", "84.776", 
"87.381", "87.438", "88.794", "91.263", "92.993")), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I sum up `total` to one single page but only those rows from `15 anys` to `74 anys` from each sheet?

The output should be something like:

[image]

Comment: You can put all the sheets from excel into a single list of dfs, or into a big dataframe, and then filter + sum by age. Without additional info about the structure of your data, it's hard to tell though

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `purrr` here:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

filter_rows <- paste0(seq(15, 74, 1), " anys")

list(df) |> 
 set_names(
   "1980-01"
 ) |> 
  purrr::imap_dfr(
    ~.x |> 
      filter(age %in% filter_rows) |> 
      summarise(total = sum(as.numeric(total))) |> 
      mutate(year_semester= .y) 
      
  )

     total year_semester
1 1310.338       1980-01
```